# Improve button response time

Tags: java, android

I've got a main menu, which contains many buttons. If I push any button, it does nothing for 2/3 sec and than load the activity. The loaded activity contains a viewpager with 6 pages or more. Anybody got an idea how I increase the perfomance of my buttons?

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ImageButton button_01, button_02, button_03, button_04, button_05, button_06, button_07, button_08, button_09, button_10, button_11, button_12, button_13;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private String mActivityTitle;
    public static KapitelAnlage kapitelAnlage;
    public static SharedPreferences pref;
    public static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
        editor = pref.edit();


        kapitelAnlage = new KapitelAnlage();

        button_01 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_01);
        button_01.setOnClickListener(this);


        button_02 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_02);
        button_02.setOnClickListener(this);


        button_03 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_03);
        button_03.setOnClickListener(this);

        button_04 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_04);
        button_04.setOnClickListener(this);
        //button_04.setEnabled(false);
        //button_04.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

        button_05 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_05);
        button_05.setOnClickListener(this);
        //button_05.setEnabled(false);
        //button_05.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);


        button_06 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_06);
        button_06.setOnClickListener(this);
        //button_06.setEnabled(false);
        //button_06.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);


        button_07 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_07);
        button_07.setOnClickListener(this);
        //button_07.setEnabled(false);
        //button_07.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

        button_08 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_08);
        button_08.setOnClickListener(this);
        //button_08.setEnabled(false);
        //button_08.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);


        button_09 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_09);
        button_09.setOnClickListener(this);
        //button_08.setEnabled(false);
        //button_08.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);


        button_10 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_10);
        button_10.setOnClickListener(this);
        //button_08.setEnabled(false);
        //button_08.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);


        button_11 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_11);
        button_11.setOnClickListener(this);
        //button_08.setEnabled(false);
        //button_08.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);


        button_12 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_12);
        button_12.setOnClickListener(this);
        //button_08.setEnabled(false);
        //button_08.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

        button_13 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_13);
        button_13.setOnClickListener(this);
        //button_08.setEnabled(false);
        //button_08.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);


        buttonAktiviere();
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();

        addDrawerItems();
        setupDrawer();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == button_01) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Kapitel_01.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            kapitelAnlage.setKapitel(Kapitel.Kapitel_01);

        } else if (v == button_02) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Kapitel_02.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            kapitelAnlage.setKapitel(Kapitel.Kapitel_02);

        } else if (v == button_03) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Kapitel_03.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            kapitelAnlage.setKapitel(Kapitel.Kapitel_03);

        } else if (v == button_04) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Kapitel_04.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            kapitelAnlage.setKapitel(Kapitel.Kapitel_04);
        } else if (v == button_05) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Kapitel_05.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            kapitelAnlage.setKapitel(Kapitel.Kapitel_05);
        } else if (v == button_06) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Kapitel_06.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            kapitelAnlage.setKapitel(Kapitel.Kapitel_06);
        } else if (v == button_07) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Kapitel_07.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            kapitelAnlage.setKapitel(Kapitel.Kapitel_07);
        } else if (v == button_08) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Kapitel_08.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            kapitelAnlage.setKapitel(Kapitel.Kapitel_08);
        } else if (v == button_09) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Kapitel_09.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            kapitelAnlage.setKapitel(Kapitel.Kapitel_09);
        } else if (v == button_10) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Kapitel_10.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            kapitelAnlage.setKapitel(Kapitel.Kapitel_10);
        } else if (v == button_11) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Kapitel_11.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            kapitelAnlage.setKapitel(Kapitel.Kapitel_11);
        } else if (v == button_12) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Kapitel_12.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            kapitelAnlage.setKapitel(Kapitel.Kapitel_12);
        } else if (v == button_13) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Kapitel_13.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            kapitelAnlage.setKapitel(Kapitel.Kapitel_13);
        }
    }


    private void addDrawerItems() {
        String[] osArray = {"Aktien", "Renten", "Immobilien", "Blog", "Kontakt"};
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, osArray);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Time for an upgrade!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupDrawer() {

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {


            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Navigation!");
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mActivityTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.optionsmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();


        // Activate the navigation drawer toggle
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.item2) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Impressum.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void buttonAktiviere() {


        if (checkKap("Kap03")) {
            buttonEnable(button_04);
            Log.d("Meine APP", "Kapitel 4 ist freigeschaltet");


        }

    }


    public boolean checkKap(String kap) {

        boolean check = pref.getBoolean(kap, false);
        if (check) {
            return true;
        } else return false;


    }


    public void buttonEnable(ImageButton btn) {
        btn.getBackground().setColorFilter(null);
        btn.setEnabled(true);
    }



}
```

And:

```
public class Kapitel_01 extends Activity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
    private LinearLayout dotsLayout;
    private TextView[] dots;
    private int[] layouts;
    private Button btnNext;
    private ImageView image_1_a, image_1_b;
    private WebView header_1_a,text_1_a;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_slider);



        layouts = new int[]{
                R.layout.slide_type_a,
                R.layout.slide_type_a,
                R.layout.slide_type_c,
                R.layout.slide_type_a,
                R.layout.slide_type_a,
                R.layout.slide_type_b,
                R.layout.slide_type_b,
                R.layout.slide_type_b,
                R.layout.slide_type_b,
                R.layout.startquiz_layout};

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(Setting.getOffscreenSet(layouts.length));
        dotsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDots);
        btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);


        // adding bottom dots
        addBottomDots(0);

        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);


    }

    public void btnQuizStart(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Quiz.class);
        image_1_a = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_slide_type_a_1);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }


    public void btnNextClick(View v) {
        // checking for last page
        // if last page home screen will be launched
        int current = getItem(1);
        if (current < layouts.length) {
            // move to next screen
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(current);
        } else {
            launchHomeScreen();
        }
    }


    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            addBottomDots(position);

            // changing the next button text 'NEXT' / 'GOT IT'
            if (position == layouts.length - 1) {
                // last page. make button text to GOT IT
                btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.start));

            } else {
                // still pages are left
                btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.next));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }
    };


    private void addBottomDots(int currentPage) {
        dots = new TextView[layouts.length];

        dotsLayout.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i] = new TextView(this);
            dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
            dots[i].setTextSize(35);
            dots[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.inactive_dots));
            dotsLayout.addView(dots[i]);
        }

        if (dots.length > 0)
            dots[currentPage].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.active_dots));
    }


    private int getItem(int i) {


        return viewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
    }

    private void launchHomeScreen() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }


    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


        public ViewPagerAdapter() {

        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {



            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            HTMLPre preparer = new HTMLPre();



            String font = "SourceSansPro-Regular";

            View one_one = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_type_a, container, false);
            final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) one_one.findViewById(R.id.loadscreen);
            layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            dotsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDots);
            dotsLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);



            WebView header_1_a = (WebView) one_one.findViewById(R.id.header_slide_type_a_1);
            preparer.loadHTLMContentHeader(getString(R.string.Historie9_header), header_1_a, font);
            image_1_a = (ImageView) one_one.findViewById(R.id.image_slide_type_a_1);
            image_1_a.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture_kap01_01);
            WebView text_1_a = (WebView) one_one.findViewById(R.id.text_slide_type_a_1);
            preparer.loadHTLMContentText(getString(R.string.Historie9), text_1_a, font);


            View one = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_type_a, container, false);


            header_1_a = (WebView) one.findViewById(R.id.header_slide_type_a_1);
            preparer.loadHTLMContentHeader(getString(R.string.Historie1_header), header_1_a, font);
            image_1_a = (ImageView) one.findViewById(R.id.image_slide_type_a_1);
            image_1_a.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture_kap01_01);
            text_1_a = (WebView) one.findViewById(R.id.text_slide_type_a_1);
            preparer.loadHTLMContentText(getString(R.string.Historie1), text_1_a, font);


            View two = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_type_c, container, false);

            image_1_a = (ImageView) two.findViewById(R.id.image_slide_type_c_1);
            image_1_a.setImageResource(R.drawable.boerse_antwerpen);
            text_1_a = (WebView) two.findViewById(R.id.text_slide_type_c_1);
            preparer.loadHTLMContentText(getString(R.string.Historie2), text_1_a, font);


            View three = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_type_a, container, false);

            header_1_a = (WebView) three.findViewById(R.id.header_slide_type_a_1);
            preparer.loadHTLMContentHeader(getString(R.string.Historie3_header), header_1_a, font);
            image_1_a = (ImageView) three.findViewById(R.id.image_slide_type_a_1);
            image_1_a.setImageResource(R.drawable.parketthandel);
            text_1_a = (WebView) three.findViewById(R.id.text_slide_type_a_1);
            preparer.loadHTLMContentText(getString(R.string.Historie3), text_1_a, font);


            View four = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_type_a, container, false);

            header_1_a = (WebView) four.findViewById(R.id.header_slide_type_a_1);
            preparer.loadHTLMContentHeader(getString(R.string.Historie4_header), header_1_a, font);
            image_1_a = (ImageView) four.findViewById(R.id.image_slide_type_a_1);
            image_1_a.setImageResource(R.drawable.parketthandel);
            text_1_a = (WebView) four.findViewById(R.id.text_slide_type_a_1);
            preparer.loadHTLMContentText(getString(R.string.Historie4), text_1_a, font);


            View five = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_type_b, container, false);

            WebView header_1_b = (WebView) five.findViewById(R.id.header_slide_type_b_1);
            preparer.loadHTLMContentHeader(getString(R.string.Historie5_header), header_1_b, font);
            View layout_1_b = (View) five.findViewById(R.id.layout_slide_type_b_1);
            layout_1_b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.london_old_stock_exchange);


            View six = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_type_b, container, false);

            header_1_b = (WebView) six.findViewById(R.id.header_slide_type_b_1);
            preparer.loadHTLMContentHeader(getString(R.string.Historie6_header), header_1_b, font);
            layout_1_b = (View) six.findViewById(R.id.layout_slide_type_b_1);
            layout_1_b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.frankfurt_old_stock);

            View seven = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_type_b, container, false);

            header_1_b = (WebView) seven.findViewById(R.id.header_slide_type_b_1);
            preparer.loadHTLMContentHeader(getString(R.string.Historie7_header), header_1_b, font);
            layout_1_b = (View) seven.findViewById(R.id.layout_slide_type_b_1);
            layout_1_b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.newyork_stock_old);

            View eight = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_type_b, container, false);

            header_1_b = (WebView) eight.findViewById(R.id.header_slide_type_b_1);
            preparer.loadHTLMContentHeader(getString(R.string.Historie8_header), header_1_b, font);
            layout_1_b = (View) eight.findViewById(R.id.layout_slide_type_b_1);
            layout_1_b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tokio_boerse);


            View nine = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.startquiz_layout, container, false);
            View viewarr[] = {one_one, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine};
            container.addView(viewarr[position]);
            layout.postDelayed(new Runnable() { public void run() { layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            dotsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);} }, 3000);


            return viewarr[position];


        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return layouts.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
            return view == obj;
        }


        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            View view = (View) object;

            container.removeView(view);
        }
    }


}
```

The mainactivity loads the kapitel_01 class if i push the button_01.

Comment: Try to use a fragment rather than an activity. That would decrease the loading time.

Comment: also, attach a listener to each button and remove that long list of if v == button_n. It won't change performance significantly but it would make you look sane

Comment: @zed so i should use fragments which contains a viewpager with my pages instead of a activity?

Comment: That would decrease the load time for the buttons, but would increase the load time for the current activity. One other thing you can do is to generate the items in the viewpager dynamically when requested, and one more thing; make sure that you are using resources (such as drawables) of efficient small sizes.

Comment: @zed ok thank you i wilm try the fragments later